# Using facebook javascript sdk to process fql query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have just put implemented Facebook connect on my web-site using the JavaScript SDK. Now I would like to process an fql query.

So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible using only JavaScript fql as "`SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friends WHERE uid2=me())`" ?
2. Because when I tried some PHP SDK code using the facebook doc

PHP:

```
$app_id = 'MY_ID';
$app_secret = 'MY_APP_SECRET';
$my_url = 'POST_AUTH_URL';
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
```

`$_REQUEST["code"]` is quite normally not recognized and I don't know what is the "`'POST_AUTH_URL'`" because I didn't use the PHP SDK to process the Facebook-connect. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `method: 'fql.query'` is part of the **deprecated** REST API.

A better, future-proof way IMHO is to send your queries against the Graph API:

```
FB.api("/fql?q={your urlencoded query}", callback() { … } );
```

Comment: +1 Indeed it would be preferable to stay away from API's in the process of deprecation.

Comment: I know that this is ole but can you provide the link for this.

Answer (score 9):

Using the JavaScript SDK you can easily execute an FQL query -

```
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
  },
  function(response) {
    alert('Your name is ' + response[0].name);
  }
);
```

Don't forget to request all the permissions you need before executing any queries...

---

Reference - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment yet but to clarify [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10998422/2133820); what worked for me was formatting the FQL API call the same way I would a Graph API call with {fields: "ex1,ex2"}:

```
var fqlRequest = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me()";
FB.api("/fql",{q:fqlRequest}, function(response){
    // do cool stuff with response here
});
```

Note that I did NOT have to URL encode the string and it worked fine for me (I had used
`encodeURI(fqlRequest)` before and it returned an `unexpected %` error).

Also remember to quote literals if you use them:

```
var id = "1234567890";
var fqlRequest = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = ' " + id + " ' ";
```

Comment: Do you really want spaces before/after the `id`? I seems to me you should have `"... uid = '" + id + "'";` which I know is harder to read, but with the spaces it will likely fail, right?