# Javascript: Make a function wait until the query has finished

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

So i make a facebook query ( fql ) in a function, and i need to use the returned results in another function, but the query takes some time. How can i delay the second function until the whole query loaded?

Comment: query function does not have callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by passing callback function to [`FB.api`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/):

```
FB.api('/fql', {q: 'YOUR QUERY HERE'}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**BTW**, you probably may want to read next couple of questions to get more familiar with how closures and asynchronous execution works in JavaScript.

- [Call An Asynchronous Javascript Function Synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously)
- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997805/using-facebook-javascript-sdk-to-proceed-fql-query):

```
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
  },
  function(response) {
    // !!! here you should write second function !!!
    amotherFunction(response);
    alert('Your name is ' + response[0].name);
  }
);
```

`function(response){}` will fire after query has completed

Comment: In some queries it takes longer to take the response, and if i return the response, and call it in a function, the second function will load before the query ( because the query takes longer).

Comment: @StefanPerju, you cannot just return the result from closure function you need to pass it other way.

Comment: @Juicy Scripter Or, i could call the function i need, in this one. But only after the query finished loading. More precisely, i need to put the retrieved info in a json, and then call a function with this json as parameter.